# Selected Field in PHP

Tags: php, select

I have a select box where the user chooses a sex (gender) from a drop down, and their choice is specified with "selected" in the select tag.  But the box always ends up 'Choose'. What is wrong in the following syntax?

```
echo"<select name='sex'>
<option value='N' '". ($info['sex'] == "N" ? 'selected=selected':'') ."'>Choose</option>
<option value='M' '". ($info['sex'] == "M" ? 'selected=selected':'') ."'>Male</option>    
<option value='F' '". ($info['sex'] == "F" ? 'selected=selected':'') ."'>Female</option> 
</select>";
```

The `$info['sex']` is from a consult SQL that return always N, M or F.

Comment: does `$info['sex']` return the correct result?

Comment: Have you looked at the source to make sure one of the options is showing "selected=selected"? The quotes aren't important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `selected=selected` is being quoted and output like

```
<option value='N' 'selected=selected'>
```

when you run your code, use this

```
echo"<select name='sex'>
<option value='N' ". ($info['sex'] == "N" ? 'selected=\'selected\'':'') .">Choose</option>
<option value='M' ". ($info['sex'] == "M" ? 'selected=\'selected\'':'') .">Male</option>    
<option value='F' ". ($info['sex'] == "F" ? 'selected=\'selected\'':'') .">Female</option> 
</select>";
```

notice the escaped quotes at `'selected=\'selected\''` and the lack of single-quotes at `". ($info['sex']` and `.">`

demo: http://codepad.org/AX95BzTR

here's a fiddle showing your problematic output: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/KB4rv

Comment: Even though it is better to enclose it with quotes - it wouldn't change anything: http://jsfiddle.net/7YbMf/

Comment: @zerkms true, but this outputs html that looks like the rest of OP's code, like `value='N'`, clean consistent outputted code is my aim here...

Comment: it is consistent indeed, but it doesn't solve the issue at all

Comment: @zerkms then answer the question yourself. this is the bug, and my answer solves it. I've added a link to a demo...

Comment: 1. your answer couldn't solve it, because quotes literally change nothing 2. it is not possible to answer the question without additional details. http://codepad.org/oJ32ptCM -- this works as well. So, not an answer

Comment: It could be that your setting `$info['sex'] = F;`. The original code does not gurantee it's set

Comment: It is the quotes!!! If the HTML is not parsed correctly then the default would show up, your default being "Choose". Remove the quotes and try it for yourself. The you will see what is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
selected=\"selected\"
```

Comment: It won't matter if you use single or double quotes as long as it doesn't look like this: 'selected=selected' it should look like this: selected=selected or selected="selected" or selected='selected'

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know if this is the answer, but try this:
`". (($info['sex'] == "N") ? ('selected=\'selected\''):(NULL)) ."`

Also look if you  tag has autocomplete="off" or hit ctrl + f5 a few times to be sure. This happend to me alot in the past

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to avoid this style of coding and include PHP in HTML not the other way.

For example it can be done like this:

```
<?php
$sex = "F"; //mockup data from DB
?>

<select>
        <option <?= $sex=="M" ? "selected='selected'" : "" ?> value='M' >Male</option>
        <option <?= $sex=="F" ? "selected='selected'" : "" ?> value='F' >Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: using the `<?= ?>` shortcut might break when transporting this code, before php 5.2 you had to enable/install it for it to work... It's not a bug, just something to be aware of...

Comment: Yes it's true. To be more precise in PHP 5.3 "short_open_tag = On" must set in php.ini
In PHP 5.4 it has been changed and this syntax always works.

Answer (score 0):

if `$info['sex']` is N or M or F;

```
    echo "<select name=\"sex\">
    <option value=\"N\" ". ($info['sex'] == "N" ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "") .">Choose</option>
    <option value=\"M\" ". ($info['sex'] == "M" ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "") .">Male</option>    
    <option value=\"F\" ". ($info['sex'] == "F" ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "") .">Female</option> 
    </select>";
```

PS: Single quotes is valid to use in HTML but it's a bad trend like justin biebering.